Piping python to file gives UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '...' in position ...: character maps to <undefined>
In the Windows terminal, Python 3.x printing a unicode character works fine; it correctly outputs: :
python -c "print('')"

But piping the same command to a file:
python -c "print('')" > log.txt

causes:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\anaconda3\envs\env6\Lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\U0001f4c2' in position 0: character maps to <undefined>

How to avoid this UnicodeEncodeError?

Do you mean "terminal" instead of "text file" in one of the two cases? In any case, how to set up the terminal for Unicode support is an often-answered question here.

Thanks! That was a mistake from copyediting; I have fixed it now.

The UnicodeEncodeError occurs because the default encoding in the Windows command prompt is cp1252, which cannot encode certain Unicode characters.  cp1252 is a legacy single-byte character encoding that is used by default (as the "ANSI code page") in Microsoft Windows.  The correct modern encoding to use is utf-8.
To avoid the error, you can explicitly set the encoding to utf-8 when redirecting the output to a file. You can set the PYTHONIOENCODING environment variable to utf-8 temporarily for the command:
set PYTHONIOENCODING=utf-8 && python -c "print('')" > log.txt

This sets the environment variable PYTHONIOENCODING to utf-8 for the duration of the command.
